# Checkbox array isn't being sent from form to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

```
Only the name and email are being sent, and not the array. 
Here is the form :

<form class="form-horizontal" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm">
        <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend>Préinscription</legend>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="text">Nom</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="name" name="Préinscription" type="text" placeholder="Veuillez entrer votre nom." class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="email" name="Préinscription" type="email" placeholder="Veuillez entrer votre adresse mail." class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Samedi 5 août</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-0">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes5-0" value="1">
                  Saint amour
                </label>
                </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes5-1" value="2">
                  Polisse
                </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Dimanche 6 août</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-0">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes6-0" value="1">
                  La vie d'Adèle
                </label>
                </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes6-1" value="2">
                  De rouille et d'os
                </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Lundi 7 août</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-0">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes7-0" value="1">
                  Bang gang
                </label>
                </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes7-1" value="2">
                  Médecin de campagne
                </label>
                </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes7-2" value="3">
                  Les innocentes
                </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Mardi 8 août</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-0">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes8-0" value="1">
                  La loi du marché
                </label>
                </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes8-1" value="2">
                  Les malheurs de sophie
                </label>
                </div>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label for="checkboxes-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" id="checkboxes8-2" value="3">
                  Ma loute
                </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <br/>
            <!-- Button -->
            <div id="success"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
              </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And here is the PHP that goes with it :

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));

$filmsSelectionner= 'Aucun';
if(isset($_POST['checkboxes']) && is_array($_POST['checkboxes']) && count($_POST['checkboxes']) > 0){
    $filmsSelectionner= implode(', ', $_POST['checkboxes']);
}

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'xxx@hotmail.com';
$email_subject = "Nouvel preinscription de la part de $name";
$email_body = "Vous avez reçu une nouvelle préinscription depuis votre forumalaire sur le site de Les Films de Plein Air.\n\n"."Voici les détails:\n\nNom: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nFilms à laquel il y sera: $filmsSelectionner\n\n";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Here is the AJAX used to send the form:

```
// Contact Form Scripts

$(function() {

    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Votre message a bien été envoyé. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Désolé" + firstName + ", il semble que le serveur de messagerie ne répond plus. Veuillez réessayer plus tard!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

And in my email, both the text and the email are being sent. Also, the $filmsSelectionner is being sent as well and it's value is Aucun. That means the problem is coming from the if condition. I need help, I'm a beginner ! :)

Comment: You do realise that checkboxes are only sent to the script if they are actually checked dont you

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the answer! Yes, I do realize. And that's why I'm asking why isn't it working when I check them and then submit.

Comment: And you will only be sent the `value` attribute content. Which you have duplicates

Comment: The `id` attribute is irrelevant to PHP that is only any use to javascript

Comment: I would add a `print_r($_POST['checkboxes'])` to the beginning of your script to see what you are getting from the form

Comment: do `var_dump($_POST); die;` at the top of your script. What do you see?

Comment: @RiggsFolly nothing is being printed, there's nothing in checkboxes. So does that mean nothing is being sent from the form? Why? PS: I changed the values to have unique values in each one.

Comment: @AndreiSavin there's no error_log being created when I var_dump the $_POST variable.

Comment: You send the form with ajax?

Comment: is it possible that, due to some missing html closing tags, your html form element is being closed before the checkboxes? inspect the form element in the browser console to see whether the checkbox inputs are actually inside the form

Comment: @Shibi yes, I added the AJAX code up there

Comment: @danyamachine all tags are closed :) not a tags problem

Comment: You don't send the checkboxes in the ajax data...

Comment: @Shibi thanks ! I got it to work out ! REALLY appreciated !! I told you I'm a beginner haha :P

Comment: Good glad you figure it out :)